# My service call function is giving response when called in another function

Tags: angular, race-condition, angular-services

I am trying to call a function which is indeed a service call (a http request), I want to use that response for the lines below the function call. as the response is depended upon it.

And this code below is in another component, which I am calling from a parent component.

getAdvanceSettings in called from a service file.

```
service file call. 
getAdvanceSettings(botName: string) {
    return this.http.get(
      `/botName/../advanced_settings`,
    );
  }

getAdvancedSettings() {
    this.NotifSRV.getAdvanceSettings(this.bot_name).subscribe((res: any) => {
     console.log('res', res);
    this.advanced_settings = res;
     console.log('advanced_settings', this.advanced_settings);
   });
   return;
  }

getNotifDetails(res: any, notifId: number) {
    if (res || notifId) {
      ....... code here
    } else {
      this.getAdvancedSettings();
      console.log('advacned-1', this.advanced_settings);
      this.endDate = "";
      this.endAfter = null;
      this.advanced_settings['repeat']['number'] = 1;
      // this.repEvSelected = Object.values(this.advanced_settings['repeat']['every']['choices'])[0];
      this.advanced_settings['repeat']['on']['selected'] = [];
      this.advanced_settings['repeat']['month_number'] = 0;
      this.selectedROnVals = {};
      this.selEndOpt = 'never';
      this.advanced_settings['ends'][this.selEndOpt] = true;
      console.log('advacned-2', this.advanced_settings);
    }
  }
```

I tried to call the function in constructor so that I can use the response, it did not work, called in ngOnInt function, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps...

```
getAdvancedSettings() {
    return this.NotifSRV.getAdvanceSettings(this.bot_name)
    .pipe(map((res: any) => {
      console.log('res', res);
      this.advanced_settings = res;
      console.log('advanced_settings', this.advanced_settings);
      return res;
  }));
}

getNotifDetails(res: any, notifId: number) {
  if (res || notifId) {
  ....... code here
  } else {
     this.getAdvancedSettings().subscribe(response =>
       this.advanced_settings = response;
       console.log('advacned-1', this.advanced_settings);
       this.endDate = "";
       this.endAfter = null;
       this.advanced_settings['repeat']['number'] = 1;
       // this.repEvSelected = 
       Object.values(this.advanced_settings['repeat']['every']['choices'])[0];
       this.advanced_settings['repeat']['on']['selected'] = [];
       this.advanced_settings['repeat']['month_number'] = 0;
       this.selectedROnVals = {};
       this.selEndOpt = 'never';
       this.advanced_settings['ends'][this.selEndOpt] = true;
       console.log('advacned-2', this.advanced_settings);
    });
}
```

Comment: I cannot this approach if I use getAdvancedSettings() in the constructor right ?

Comment: I updated the answer according your comment. Now you can do it easily.

Comment: it says cannot find map,but Map can be used. I don't think that is correct

Comment: The answer you gave is good, but I shouldn't subscribe the response in a function, the subscription has to be done outside of getNotifDetails()

Comment: where are you calling getNotifDetails? Also I miss one bracket - probably that's why you got an error.

Comment: as it's a http call - I don't see any reasons to do not call it from your function. you don't have to unsubscribe etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253985/discussion-between-charger-ang-and-eugene-kr).